# Getting the filenames of the files Cmake add_library() generates

Tags: windows, cmake, shared-libraries

Using CMake 3.23, I am trying to get the names of the files that `add_library()` generates for a target in Windows.

```
add_library(talib source.cpp source.h)
```

It generates the following files:

```
talib.dll
talib.lib
talib.pdb
```

Is there any way to get the names of the above files? `$<TARGET_FILE:talib>` only gives me `talib.dll`, how can I get the rest of the filenames, and will it work for Linux libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following generator expressions. This is mostly quoting the documentation here:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html

- `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` -- Full path to the `tgt` binary file. For shared libraries, this is the dynamic object file on all platforms.
- `$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:tgt>` -- File used when linking to the `tgt` target. This will usually be the same as `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>`, but for a shared library on DLL platforms, it would be the `.lib` import library associated with the DLL.
- `$<TARGET_PDB_FILE:tgt>` -- Full path to the linker generated program database file (`.pdb`) where tgt is the name of a target.

All of these resolve to absolute paths. The first two work on all systems (but might duplicate each other). The last one only works on PDB systems and will throw a fatal error that reads `TARGET_PDB_FILE is not supported by the target linker.` on other systems.

To detect whether you are on a PDB system, you can check the variable `CMAKE_<LANG>_LINKER_SUPPORTS_PDB`, where `<LANG>` is `C`, `CXX`, etc.